# How to remove border from drop down list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm new to flutter , and I'm trying to design this widget , and am wondering how to add the blue color at the left corner of this drop down list, remove the border of the drop down list , and make the text at the center

this is what i've tried so far:

```
    body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
        Container(
         // width: 200,
            //height: 100,
          color: Colors.purpleAccent,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
       child: DropdownButton<String>(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedFacultyItem = value;
            });
          },
          value: selectedFacultyItem,

          // Hide the default underline
          underline: Container(),
          hint: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Student attendance percentage ',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          isExpanded: true,
          items: items
            .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item, child: Text(item)))
            .toList(),

        ),),
    Container(
        width: 20,
    height: 75,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xff095BA4),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
   topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12))))
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove underline by using `underline: const SizedBox()` on `DropdownButton`. To decorate the UI and left color bar, I am using `Container` and `ClipRRect` widgets.

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 12,
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.1),
      border: const Border(
        left: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 8,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 12),
      elevation: 0,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      underline: const SizedBox(),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
      },
    
  ),)
);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can find more about [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)